# Setting the row order of tr tags

Tags: javascript, html, row

Wondering if there is a attribute for the `tr` tag that you can set that determines which order it will render on the webpage in.

I have code that dynamically creates a table based on an array, in this array there is also a piece of data that says which order each row is in, but the data comes in arbitrarily.

Take this example:

```
<table>
    <tr row="0">A</tr>
    <tr row="2">C</tr>
    <tr row="1">B</tr>
<table>
```

The table would be structured this way in the dom structure, but when rendered i'd like it to show up like this:

```
<table>
    <tr row="0">A</tr>
    <tr row="1">B</tr>
    <tr row="2">C</tr>
<table>
```

If this `row` attribute or anything similar doesn't exist can I do it with JavaScript?

Comment: There's really no way to sort source data?

Comment: There is a way with Jquery. Search it. It has been answered. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> I have code that dynamically creates a table based on an array

You should [sort the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript) in the order that you want before you build the table.

For example, to sort by a property called "index":

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return +(a.index > b.index);
})
```

If your source data is complex you could define a separate function that returns the property that should ultimately be used to sort the table:

```
function getSortKey(element) {
  // write the logic to return your "row" attribute. It can be
  //  as complex as necessary (but it must be synchronous).
  // a made-up example:
  return element.members ? 
    ? element.members[0].name
    : element.defaultName  ;
}

myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return +(getSortKey(a) > getSortKey(b));
})
```

There isn't a built-in way to change the order that rows are rendering in, and changing the order with JavaScript after rendering is inefficient.

Comment: Inefficient doesn't = impossible. The question was/is, how.

Comment: But the thing is this huge array is extremely complicated, it is nested with a variant amount of data in each array, inside other arrays inside objects. How do i loop twice inside the sort function for example?

Comment: You could break out the code that works out the sort key into a function. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @joews The thing i don't understand in your sort function, something i've seen a lot is members[0]. I need to loop through all the members in that, and then inside those i need to loop through members again. Not only base it on the first element.

Comment: You can use any logic inside getSortKey. You could loop or call other functions, but you must eventually return a single value to compare. For you this will be the value that you put into the tr row attribute.

Comment: @joews This makes no sense, the values i need to compare are nested in objects, how can i sort the outside objects that contain these values? {A:[1,4,2],B:[5,3,6]} Now which come first, B or A? Note that the values can be variant, and the "1,2,4" etc are objects themselves and the real sort value is inside these again.

Comment: How do you work out the `row` attribute in your example? That value, wherever it comes from, is what you should return from `getSortKey`. If you can show me some of your nested data I can help you with the exact comparator that you need.

Comment: @joews The entire list structure is returned from a server, i am not the one who compiles it and i cannot change the way it is structured. How would you solve this {A:[1,4,2],B:[5,3,6]}? The thing is i can sort in the individual array in A and B, but i need the numbers inside to take into consideration every value outside as well, or else it is wrong. When i loop through this list i need it to produce 123456. But 4 and 3 aren't in the same array.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't seem to understand each other. I can't tell you which field to use to sort your data, but I've shown you the structure that you can use to choose yourself. Your question says _"in this array there is also a piece of data that says which order each row is in"_. You need `getSortKey` to return that piece of data, wherever it is found in your nested structure. If that doesn't help you, then I'm afraid I'll have to bow out.

Comment: @joews My question is really simple, how would you sort {A:[1,4,2],B:[5,3,6]}, so that when i loop through it it returns 123456. Keep in mind the amount of data in these arrays can vary, and the A and B wrapper outside needs to be maintained.

Comment: Ah, OK. Because that's an Object, not an array, you need to create a new array to hold the collected, sorted values: `var allValues = []; for(key in data) {
  allValues.push.apply(allValues, data[key])
}; allValues.sort();` That will sort nested primitive values. If you have complex values you'll need to use a sort callback like in my answer.

Comment: Like i said the A and B wrapper outside needs to be maintained. This does not allow that. It is clear you do not understand my question so i will post again.

Comment: I thought you meant "must not be changed", which this fulfils. I thought your expected output was a single array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Do you mean that the output should be `{ A: [1,2,4], B: [ 3,5,6 ] }` ?

Comment: @joews Yes you are understanding more, the output needs to be [1,2,3,4,5,6]. But no you cannot move one value inside one of the array into the other, basically as i see it this is a object structure that is unsortable. And i need to sort it later after i've added it to the table. You may ask why i need to maintain the A B, it is because there are values on this level that i use on the numbers when i loop through the object.

Comment: I'm afraid that, like the users who looked at your other question, I can't make sense of your requirement. My code several comments up outputs `[1,2,3,4,5,6].` You _can't_ have both `{ A: [...], B: [...] }` __and__ `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` as your output. It has to be an Object (cannot be sorted) _or_ an Array (can be sorted).  The code in my comments is my best attempt.

Comment: @joews Yes like i said, it is unsortable. Thats why i need to do it after I've inserted them. The 1,2,3,4,5,6 have a property that says which row they need to be in, but it is not possible to sort the source data.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should probably fix from higher up before the table is parsed to the DOM, but something along these lines could work (fyi no time to debug it right now)

```
var table_tr = [];
jQuery("#mytable").find("tr").each(function(){
 table_tr[parseInt(jQuery(this).attr("row"))] = jQuery(this).clone(true,true);
 jQuery(this).remove();
});
jQuery.each(table_tr,function(index,element){
 jQuery("#mytable").append(element);
});
```

EDIT:
Kinda ugly, but it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/ezbd9huv/
Seriously though, you should consider fixing it before it prints to the DOM~